# flask rest API crash after frequent request, how to find out what cause that?

Tags: rest, flask

I build a rest API service using flask framework to provide password query and  update utility.Service crash without notice,so i write a shell script to monitor that,make sure that it crash  now and then.However, I can not figure out what was going wrong.Debug mode just print request info,but not print out down-crash info.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a try-catch and logging will help you. Still if you can share your code I may able to help further.

If you want to know how to logging refer this [How to maintain logs in Falcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718868/how-to-maintain-logs-in-falcon/41677596#41677596)

Please provide more details if possible.

Comment: tks. My code snippets here:

def pmsd_start():
    pmsd_status()
    if RUN == 'on':
        return 
    else:
        p = Process(target= app.run, args=('0.0.0.0',DEFAULT_PORT))
        p1 = Process(target= app.run, args=('0.0.0.0',DEFAULT_PORT1))
        p.start()
        p1.start()
        print "Start pmsd:"," "*13,"[ ","\033["+"0;32"+"m"+'OK'+"\033[0m"," ]"
        os._exit(0)
        
I use flask app to monitor on two different port with each running by a child process,when launched,ports start listening,my  self-defined service keep status of starting.